# Trying to validate that at least one checkbox is checked angularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Trying to figure out the best way to stay on the same page alerting the user if they have failed to check at least one checkbox.

HTML:

```
<div class="col3">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.value5" ng-true-value="'Togetherness'" ng-false-value="">
<span class="checkboxtext">
    Togetherness
</span><br>
<!--<p>We value our people and recognize that <strong>Together</strong> we achieve superior results.</p><br>-->
<div class="col3">

    <a ui-sref="form.submit">
        <button name="button" ng-click="SaveValue()">Continue</button>
    </a>
```

Back-end angularJS to check if one of the boxes was checked-

```
$scope.SaveValue = function () {
    var valueStatus = [];
    if ($scope.value1 === "Methodical")
    {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value1);
    }
    if ($scope.value2 === "Relentless")
    {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value2);
    }
    if ($scope.value3 === "Togetherness")
    {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value3)
    }
    if ($scope.value4 === "Excellent") {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value4)
    }
    if ($scope.value5 === "Ingenious") {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value5)
    }
    return valueStatus
};
```

Basically I'm wanting to make an array of these values and then return it. However, I want the user to check at least one box. I've tried redirecting back to the page if valueStatus[0] == null. However, I don't think this is the best way to validate and it does not work completely how I think it ought to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solve this is putting validation on the length of array (`valueStatus` in your case) with hidden number input. The input will have min validation on. So, if user fails to check at least one, the form is not submitted;

```
<input type="number" name="valueStatus" ng-model="valueStatus.length" min="1" style="display: none">
```

Then, you can use normal validation on `valueStatus` that is available on the form model

```
myFormName.valueStatus.$valid
```

This way, most of the logic is put into the template, which is called angularjs way ;)

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention:
You need to update the list of checked values on on-change checkbox event

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue1" on-change="updateValueStatus(checkboxValue1)">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue2" on-change="updateValueStatus(checkboxValue2)">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.updateValueStatus = function(value){
  var indexOf = $scope.valueStatus.indexOf(value);
  if(indexOf < 0) {
     $scope.valueStatus.push(value);
  } else {
     $scope.valueStatus.splice(indexOf, 1);
  }
}
```

Hope it will help people with the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the help, I like the solution! Both are of these answers have been valuable.

Comment: type="number" is important

Answer (score 0):

simply just check the `valueStatus` length is equal to 0 or not

```
$scope.SaveValue = function () {
    var valueStatus = [];
    if ($scope.value1 === "Methodical")
    {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value1);
    }
    if ($scope.value2 === "Relentless")
    {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value2);
    }
    if ($scope.value3 === "Togetherness")
    {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value3)
    }
    if ($scope.value4 === "Excellent") {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value4)
    }
    if ($scope.value5 === "Ingenious") {
        valueStatus.push($scope.value5)
    }


    if (valueStatus.length === 0 ) {
       console.log('please select atleast one select box')
    }
    return valueStatus
};
```

Edited

remove the `ui-sref` tag and change the state inside your click function

```
<button name="button" ng-click="SaveValue()">Continue</button>
```

in the saveValue function add this

```
if (valueStatus.length === 0 ) {
       console.log('please select atleast one select box')
}else{
    $state.go('form.submit') // if atleast one selected then the page will change 
}
```

Comment: That's fair, but what about forcing the user to stay on the same page, the button directs to the next page of the form, I want them to continue to stay on the page tell the valueStatus.length is not just 0.